# Trying to remap static directory with app.yaml in Google App Engine

Tags: google-app-engine, app.yaml

I have a bunch of files that are not in `/cloud/images/example/foo.png` but in fact are in `/images/example/foo.png`

I want to serve both HTML and CSS/JS/image content at the URL `/cloud/...` and have it look in the local app directory at root `/`.

Just trying to test how one would serve files that are `<img src="/cloud/images/...">` from my root directory's `/images` folder, and also browse to `/cloud/foo/` and have it serve `/foo/index.html`

This gets some success with the images:

```
# /cloud to root
- url: /cloud
  static_dir: .
```

But I'm a bit stuck outside of that.

Note: The whole site is 100% static

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To serve you html:

```
handlers:
- url: /cloud/foo/
  static_files: foo/index.html
  upload: foo/index.html
- url: /cloud/foo/(.*)
  static_files: foo/\1
  upload: foo/(.*)
```

`(.*)` will basically capture all characters and use them to locate the file in your local path, so you can have nested directories.

The first handler is actually an exception, if you want it to behave like a classic file server where `/` returns `/index.html` you have to tell the router about that special case. Personally, I wouldn't do that (save on the root, for usability); you'll have two ways to get to the same file (`/` and `/index.html`), so that could lead to confusion (even SEO problems), and it's an static site, so it's cool to use full paths like `/foo/bar/index.html`, who cares :) just my 2¢.

Comment: So there's no way to do this is a more generic way? There needs to be a separate entry for 
/cloud/foo
/cloud/bar

Etc?

Comment: Also what about /cloud/foo/bar/?

Comment: It will work fine as long as you specify the file explicitly, that's where the `(.*)` comes into play, so with the current handlers `/cloud/foo/bar/index.html` will work, it's only when you want to omit certain parts (like have `/` take you to `/index.html`) when you'd have to add more handlers.